# What will be the size of an array pointed to by its class's own pointer?

Tags: c++

```
class Size_of_dataVariable
{
public:
     int array[50];
};
```

Now if I create an object for this class using pointer like

```
Size_of_dataVariable *point = new Size_of_dataVariable;
```

And try to get the size of data member of the class `Size_of_dataVariable` using

```
sizeof(point->array)
```

Then will it print 200, or the size of the pointer?

Comment: When you tested by printing, what was the output?

Comment: @Bindu M R, your question got several downvotes (I didn't). Probably you should ask your question a bit different. Next time, try to proof that you did some research before, e.g. showing output of your code, it will help avoid that your question will be interpret wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither 50 nor the size of the pointer is correct.  `point->array` is a fixed array, not a pointer.  While there is a relationship between pointers and arrays, they are **not** the same.

Since `point->array` is a fixed array, using the `sizeof` operator on it will give you the size of the full array in bytes, specifically `50 * sizeof(int)`.

So, assuming an `int` is 4 bytes in size, `sizeof(point->array)` will be 200.

Answer (score 1):

In most contexts the name of an array decays into a pointer to its first element. Inside `sizeof` is one of the contexts where that does **not** happen; the name of the array is the name of the array, and `sizeof(point->array)` is the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it will print `200`.

Your code uses the `sizeof` operator on an array, and `sizeof` returns the size of its operand in bytes. Since each `int` is 4 bytes in size, you'll get a result of 200.

(This may not be true on all platforms; it's possible that an `int` is longer or shorter in some cases -- but it's *usually* 4 bytes).